# Create DNS server for host's domain

Tags: linux, centos, dns, bind

I want to create the DNS server for set on the domain.

For example, I want to have `ns1.domain1.com` and `ns2.domain1.com` that when setting these on each domain, domain points to the server and loads apache virtual host.

I tried the below on the CentOS 8 and I don't know the next steps:

**named.conf**

```
options {
listen-on port 53 { any; };
listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
directory   "/var/named";
dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
allow-query     { any; };
allow-transfer  { none; };
recursion yes;

dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation yes;

/* Path to ISC DLV key */
bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
   type hint;
   file "named.ca";
};
zone "aradteam.tk" IN {
   type master;
   file "forward.unixmen";
   allow-transfer { 195.248.242.31; };
};

zone "242.248.195.in-addr.arpa" IN {
   type master;
   file "reverse.unixmen";
   allow-transfer { 195.248.242.31; };
 };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

**forward.unixmen**

```
$TTL 3H
@   IN SOA  @ hostmaster.aradteam.tk. (
                0   ; serial
                3H  ; refresh
                1H  ; retry
                1W  ; expire
                3H )    ; minimum
@            IN   NS     ns1.aradteam.tk.
@            IN   NS     ns2.aradteam.tk.
@            IN   A      195.248.242.31
@            IN   MX     10 host2.aradteam.tk.
@            IN   MX     20 host3.aradteam.tk.
ns1          IN   A      195.248.242.31
ns2          IN   A      195.248.242.31
host1        IN   A      195.248.242.31
host2        IN   A      195.248.242.31
host3        IN   A      195.248.242.31
www          IN   CNAME  aradteam.tk.
mail         IN   CNAME  host2.aradteam.tk.
gopher       IN   CNAME  host3.aradteam.tk.
aradteam.tk. IN   TXT    "v=spf1 ip4:203.0.113.42 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

**reverse.unixmen**

```
$TTL 3H
@   IN SOA  @ hostmaster.aradteam.tk. (
                2    ; serial
                3H   ; refresh
                1H   ; retry
                1W   ; expire
                3H ) ; minimum
@        IN    NS    ns1.aradteam.tk.
@        IN    NS    ns2.aradteam.tk.
31        IN    PTR   ns1.aradteam.tk.
31        IN    PTR   ns2.aradteam.tk.
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to understand how to DNS works on the server, like when we setting DNS on the domain and access to the Cpanel's host  @stoney

Comment: So 1st it is not possible to user nameservers in the same domain you are querying for. `@ IN NS ns1.aradteam.tk.` tells to look for ns1.... for the addresses. how does a machine get the ip of `ns1.aradteam.tk`? In fact it can't, looping all the time.

Comment: how to I change it that it works? @stoney

Comment: At least I should know WHAT is not working.

Comment: There are two kind of name servers: authoritative and resolvers. Do you want that your local server know about your "authoritative server"? Is this question? (so on how to configure your resolver)

Comment: I want to know how to I can create DNS that each domain can access to the own virtual host on the server with setting its
I tried the above settings, but when I set ns1.aradteam.tk & ns2.aradteam.tk on other domain, the ping doesn't reply @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: Split your tasks in steps. Forget about virtual hosts for now. They are just a distraction. Are your servers authoritative? `dig @localhost your_domain` is responding right? Try using instead `@localhost` the `@ip.of.your.parent.domain.dns`

Comment: yes it's authoritative server, and dig `@ip domain` is responding right @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: So, the problem seems on your resolver (or just you didn't wait the necessary time, to have new data in cache (andthe negative cache to be empties)

Comment: You mean is if I set those DNSs on each domain, the domain should point to the server? Could you suggest me a tutorial or a sample? Maybe I was wrong @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: When I setting `ns1.aradteam.tk` &` ns2.aradteam.tk` on other domain, It doesn't point to server and ping doesn't reply @stoney

Comment: I've difficulty to understand exactly what it is your problem. I think you should edit your answer. [you can remove the reverse part, is not important here]. When you change a domain on your file, and you reload (on all DNS), you should wait TTL before you get new values.  (SOA has the value of negative cache). I'm also surprised that you are allowed to use two NS which point to the same server. Note: your NS are not delegated.... what are you doing? Please explain better.

Comment: Why (badly) obfuscating names in your introduction to then show the real names in the zonefiles? No need to obfuscate, names are public. If you are new ot this you should also forget about the reverse zone for now, it has specifics better to learn later. Also the next steps (AFTER you verified your nameservers work correctly) would be to ask your registrar to update the delegation at the registry with your new nameservers

Comment: @Ali What happens when you start `named`? ATM there is no `named` running on `195.248.242.31`. Any error messages in named log file?